# How to read resources files within a framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I built a framework and a cocoa application in Mac OS X. The framework is dynamically linked to the application. In a class of the framework, I need to read a resource file within this framework's resources folder.
The code below

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *characterCodeTable = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pymb.txt"];
```

does not work since "resourcePath" is the path to application's resources folder, not the framework's.

So how can I access the framework's resource folder in the code in this framework itself?

BTW: Is there any best practice to organize miscellaneous files in a framework/application bundle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of calling `+[NSBundle mainBundle]`, call either `+[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:]` or `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]`. The former takes an `NSString` argument of the framework's indentifier; the latter takes a `Class` argument of a class provided by the framework. Then, you can call the usual `NSBundle` paths as necessary.

Full documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I tried [[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]] resourcePath] and it works. But I'm reading the framework's resources in this framework's code. Is there any more simpler solution?

Comment: @LingfengXiong: Have you tried using `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]`?

Comment: NSString *characterCodeTable = [[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]] pathForResource:@"pymb" ofType:@"txt"]; worked like a charm :-) but I still have to write "[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]]" every time I read a resource...

Comment: You always can store that NSBundle instance somewhere, so you don’t have to write it all the time.

Answer (score 5):

There are several counter and side effects when using solutions like

```
[NSBundle mainBundle]
```

or

```
NSBundle *localBundle  = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[myObject class]]
```

when you app structure is like

```
MyContainerApp
  |------Frameworks/
        |-----------------MyFramework.framwork/
                                |-------------------Resources/
                                                           |-------------mydata.json
```

So, 
if you can create a bundle file and give it to container app (as a 3rd party framework developer) you can provide this API

```
+ (NSBundle *)frameworkBundle {
    static NSBundle* frameworkBundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        NSString* mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        NSString* frameworkBundlePath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFrameworkBundle.bundle"];
        frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];
    });
    return frameworkBundle;
}
```

**BUT**, a very super-easy, and let's say super-efficient solution is the old C header with **hexdump**

```
xxd -i mydata.json >> mydata.json.h
```

This hexdump will generate a header file with these definitions

```
unsigned char mydata_json[] = {
   // hex array
};
```

and

```
unsigned int mydata_json_len = 32227;
```

So in your framework or static library you can access to it just

```
 unsigned char *rawBytes = mydata_json;
 NSUInteger dataLen = mydata_json_len;
 NSData *serializedData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:rawBytes length:dataLen freeWhenDone:NO];
```

then you maybe want to get it into text:

```
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[rawBytes bytes]];
```

And that's it. Happy coding!